# delay timer in C#

Tags: c#, timer, delay

I try to connect my RFID to stopwatch, if that's tagging, the timer go start, if that's not, the timer go stop, but there a delay in my timer, can you help me to fix it?

In first tag, timer go normally, after that the timer delay 1 sec.

Here my code program :

```
int min1, min0, sec1, sec0 = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        label6.Text = min1 + min0.ToString() + ":" + sec1 + sec0.ToString();
        if (sec0 < 9)
        {
            sec0++;
        }
        else
        {
            sec0 = 0;
            sec1++;
        }
        if (sec1 == 6)
        {
            min0++;
            sec1 = 0;
        }

        if (min0 == 10)
        {
            min1++;
            min0 = 0;
        }
        if (min1 == 6)
        {
            min1 = 0;
            min0 = 0;
            sec1 = 0;
            sec0 = 0;
        }           
    }
```

Comment: `Timer` is different from `Stopwatch` what you are using here is a `Timer`. And what do you mean by "tagging"? Could you actually mean "ticking"?

Comment: Yes Sir, that's i mean, the timer, can you help me Sir?

Comment: I mean "tagging" is the condition if the rfid card is detect Sir

Comment: So timer1.interval should be put outside the timertick right? 
But for timer, I want to make something like stopwatch timer (00:00), not datetime.now format. The timer will count up while RFID card is on range (or tagging). So what's your suggestion? Thax for replying.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. I suggested it to be put outside of the timertick. To make it *display* like stopwatch timer you do *not* actually use `DateTime` format, but you use info in the `TimeSpan`. Please check my answer. The `DateTime` is just used as intermediate to ease your calculation greatly (by simply putting minus sign) - some more, using DateTime as intermediary compared to `Tick` (just as what you have now) would give you a lot more accurate result as `Timer_Tick` event may be drifted by some milliseconds evertime it is called, giving you accumulated error in the long run.

Comment: The line `label6.Text = ts.Hours + ":" + ts.Minutes + ":" + ts.Seconds;` using `TimeSpan` and not `DateTime` to produce its result. Thus it will show stopwatch like string format like: 0:12:17 or 1:20:20

Comment: Very helpful, thankyou Sir Ian :)

Comment: Great. Not problem. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a couple of issues with your code:

Firstly, you only need to initialize your `timer.Interval` once. But what you do is initializing your timer Interval repeatedly.

```
timer1.Interval = 1000; //declare only once somewhere else, not in the timer tick
```

Secondly, if you want to start and stop the timer from running according to your RFID connection, then you should have your `timer1.Start()` and `timer1.Stop()` methods called following your RFID card "is detected" events (which you must specify somewhere, but this is different topic. For the sake of giving example, I named the event `ConnectionChanged`)

```
private void rfid_ConnectionChanged(object sender RFIDEventArgs e){ //this is a hypothetical event handler
    if(e.IsConnected){
        timer1.Start();
    } else {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

And thirdly, use `DateTime` struct. *Don't* use `int min1, min0, sec1, sec0 = 0;`, `DateTime` struct will do the calculation job for you. What you need to do is simply re-initializing the `DateTime` every time the RFID is connected like this:

```
DateTime rfidConnectedTime; 
private void rfid_ConnectionChanged(object sender RFIDEventArgs e){ //this is a hypothetical event handler
    if(e.IsConnected){
        rfidConnectedTime = DateTime.Now;
        timer1.Start();
    } else {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

And then use it like this in your `timer1.Tick` event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - rfidConnectedTime;
    label6.Text = ts.Hours.ToString("d2") + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString("d2") + ":" + ts.Seconds.ToString("d2");
    //Note: .ToString("d2") is to print each element in two digits like 00 or 01 instead of 0 or 1
}
```

Then your code will be neat and simple.